# How can I send an email with a salesforce report attached?

Tags: reporting, scheduled-apex, future, singleemailmessage, emailfileattachment

I'm try to scheduler email send with a repor attached, but when i received the email, appear the next error in the file:

[image]

I'm use the nex Apex code:

```
global class Exporter implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        DoExport();
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void DoExport() {
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O6g000004Z0nNEAS?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(Blob.valueof(report.getContent().toString()));
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'user@example.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
    }
}
```

Could you help me with this error please?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the nicely formatted report in your email by scheduling it. See the steps here [Schedule a report](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_schedule.htm&type=5)

Comment: I need the report to be sent to a no Salesforce user